# return id of table after order the table

Tags: erlang

I have table user

```
-record(user, {id, firstname,lastname).
```

this table has for example this values

```
3  alen      dumas
5  franco    mocci
4  soma      nabi
```

I want to order this table

Itry with this code :

```
test()->
    Select = [{#user{_ = '_'}, [], ['$_']}],
Sorted = lists:sort(mnesia:dirty_select(user, Select)),
erlang:hd(lists:reverse(Sorted)).
```

and it return :

```
  5  franco    mocci
```

but my goal  is to return juste the **Id**

so I should modify the function **test** in order to return  **5**

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to    `(erlang:hd(lists:reverse(Sorted)))#user.id.`